# KafkaStreams application stops working with message Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KafkaStream application that used to work perfectly. Now no matter how many times I restart it with new Application id it never start consuming the topic and I receive this log:

```
INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams stream-client [score_redeemX-7e37d43e-12ab-4c66-984e-5f959d4e5e08] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer [Consumer clientId=score_redeemX-7e37d43e-12ab-4c66-984e-5f959d4e5e08-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeemX-7e37d43e-12ab-4c66-984e-5f959d4e5e08-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer [Consumer clientId=score_redeemX-7e37d43e-12ab-4c66-984e-5f959d4e5e08-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
```

When I set log level to debug this is the log the application produces:

```
2020-05-09 18:45:20,335 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-2] Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms
2020-05-09 18:45:20,338 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-1] Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms
2020-05-09 18:45:20,339 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-3] Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms
2020-05-09 18:45:21,339 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-2] Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms
2020-05-09 18:45:21,341 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-1] Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms
2020-05-09 18:45:21,342 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-3] Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms
2020-05-09 18:45:22,343 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-2] Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms
2020-05-09 18:45:22,344 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-1] Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms
2020-05-09 18:45:22,345 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-3] Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms
2020-05-09 18:45:22,435 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator [Consumer clientId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=score_redeem] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator ###.###.###.###:9092 (id: 2147483642 rack: null)
2020-05-09 18:45:22,437 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator [Consumer clientId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=score_redeem] Received successful Heartbeat response
2020-05-09 18:45:22,465 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator [Consumer clientId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=score_redeem] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator ###.###.###.###:9092 (id: 2147483642 rack: null)
2020-05-09 18:45:22,466 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator [Consumer clientId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=score_redeem] Received successful Heartbeat response
2020-05-09 18:45:22,468 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator [Consumer clientId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=score_redeem] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator ###.###.###.###:9092 (id: 2147483642 rack: null)
2020-05-09 18:45:22,470 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator [Consumer clientId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=score_redeem] Received successful Heartbeat response
```

No task is assigned as the log shows:

```
2020-05-09 18:43:04,322 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor stream-thread [score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-2-consumer] Constructed client metadata {0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337=ClientMetadata{hostInfo=null, consumers=[score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-2-consumer-b830a8e5-8654-40b7-8142-d1754c32268a], state=[activeTasks: ([]) standbyTasks: ([]) assignedTasks: ([]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevStandbyTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1]}} from the member subscriptions.
```

This is the part of log that shows information about leader and member:

```
2020-05-09 18:43:04,361 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator [Consumer clientId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=score_redeem] Received successful JoinGroup response: JoinGroupResponse(throttleTimeMs=0, error=NONE, generationId=4, groupProtocol=stream, memberId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-3-consumer-93905915-8b52-44b4-afd1-2a5c79a272a4, leaderId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-2-consumer-b830a8e5-8654-40b7-8142-d1754c32268a, members=)
2020-05-09 18:43:04,362 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator [Consumer clientId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=score_redeem] Sending follower SyncGroup to coordinator ###.###.###.###:9092 (id: 2147483642 rack: null): (type=SyncGroupRequest, groupId=score_redeem, generationId=4, memberId=score_redeem-0633c837-8b94-4ba3-8e59-67a4c71de337-StreamThread-3-consumer-93905915-8b52-44b4-afd1-2a5c79a272a4, groupAssignment=)
```

I have many applications running and all of them are now experiencing this. I tried making new connectors and still no luck. But I can successfully consume from those topics with kafka-console-consumer.

Another strange yet **very important** point is when I rewrote the app with Kafka Consumer API it worked fine!!!

Comment: That is just the restore consumer.  Kafka Streams uses it to restore records from a changelog topic.  You'll get this log message when it's done either restoring or if there was no restoration to do in the first place.  Have you confirmed your application isn't consuming from the source topic?  Some additional logging may help here.

Comment: @bbejeck I log everything that gets consumed and can safely confirm nothing gets consumed. I changed the log level to debug and updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @bbejeck already, the `StreamThread-1-restore-consumer` logs `Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions` and it's an `INFO` level log. It just mark the end of a potential state restore and is not related to reading input topics.

The consumer heartbeat logs just document expected behavior.

The other logs: `Committed all active tasks [] and standby tasks [] in 0ms` might indicate that there are no active tasks. This would explain why there is no progress. However, it raised the question *why* are there no tasks.

During a rebalance the task assignment is logged per instance. Can you confirm that no tasks are assigned? Furthermore, one Kafka Streams instance (per application) will act as "group leader" and thus log even more details about the assignment it computes. (Btw: what version are you using?)

Comment: The confluent version is 5.5.0 which is based on Kafka 2.5.0 as you know. I don't really know what you mean by leader log but there was a part in logs that caught my eyes. The leader has no member. I edited my question and included this piece of log too.

Comment: Hard to say. Would need to read the full logs (and StackOverflow is not the right platform to help). Might even be a bug. Did the issue start when you upgrade to 5.5.0?

Comment: Yes, indeed seems like a bug. It happened only in 5.5.0 version but not right after the upgrade.

Comment: Can you create a ticket and attach KafkaStreams and Consumer DEBUG logs?